# Borderlands 2, skin and head problems?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am having problem with the skins and head customization. I have got new heads and skins that are universal (like the Minecraft) and one's for my class and even unlocked heads. It says I unlocked it but everytime I go to change my skin/head, the items don't show up on the list. How can I fix this?

Comment: It will be skins for vehicles. I thought I unlocked a few character skins but I was mistaken :p

Comment: @Anderson256 Seconded - I didn't notice at first but it tells you on the item description what the skin is for, e.g. Bandit Technical (vehicle) or Commando (class-specific). OP, are you sure you unlocked skins/heads _for your class_?

Comment: It is also worth noting that "universal" skins are not so - for example, the Minecraft head is not universal; there is a Maya Minecraft head, an Axton Minecraft head, etc.

Answer (score 3):

They are an item that needs to be activated inside your inventory. And then they show up in the customize menu.

Comment: I do thats why they say they are "unlocked" for customize menu.